# SSL certificate on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hello ,

We have setup a Google Cloud VM .
We need to install SSL certificate in order to make sure we use secure connection.
Can you please guide us on do you provide a SSL certificate or we need to purchase it from other sources

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Serverfault. What application are you running on your VM? Are you running Wordpress or what application?

Comment: I am actually hosting few API's, the current endpoint is http and need to make it https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your own self-managed certificates, or you can use certificates that Google obtains and manages for you (Google-managed certificates). For more information about “Using self-managed SSL certificates” please refer to link[[1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs)].
A Google-managed SSL certificate is only available when using an external HTTP(S) load balancer or a SSL proxy load balancer, it is currently in pre-release state or beta and might change or have limited support. For more information, [see the product launch stages](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages).

This page[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs)discusses how to create and use Google-managed SSL certificates. However you should first select a compatible load balancer to be able to use it. To select the appropriate load balancer based on your application needs. I recommend reading this guide “Cloud Load Balancing overview” [[6]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) to better understand how to select the adequate load balancer for your application’s needs. There is also this flow chart [[7]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#flow_chart)and this feature comparison tables [[8]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features)than you can use as a reference.

Remember that only external HTTP(S) load balancers or  SSL proxy load balancers support Google-manages SSL certificates. If you wish to  compare some use cases that can be addressed by external HTTP(S) load balancers I suggest reading this article here [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#use_cases) that also discusses the limitations[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#limitations). You can learn more about SSL Proxy Load Balancer benefits here [[5]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl#benefits).